Control 24 VDC solenoid valve with relay and ESP8266
I am pretty new to electronic schematics, and I am having an issues with my circuit on controlling a 24 VDC Solenoid, in combination with a 5 VDC relay (four-channel) and an ESP8266.
I have tried to create the schematic (before I saw that you can also do it in here..). I left in only one channel, to keep a clearer overview:

The issue is that the ESP8266 is not consistently starting when powering on the system (all pins set to Low, but still one LED turned on on the Relay board). When resetting the ESP8266 with the onboard button, without changing anything else, different LEDs are burning on the Relay board.
Also the ESP8266 is not consistently connecting to the WiFi.
If I power the ESP8266 over USB instead of the external power source, then everything is working.
Software:
In the Arduino file, I am setting all GPIO's to low immediately in the set-up.
Controlling the GPIO pins low/high is then done over WiFi.
Part list:

DC trafo 220 to 24vdc, 2.5A Max
DC-DC converter: 24 to 5 vdc
ESP8266: Wemos D1 mini pro
Relay module: 5VDC four-channel
Solenoid valve: Rainbird 100-HV

Thank you very much for the help in advance!

It sounds like the 24 to 5 V step-down converter isn't doing its job very well. What is the voltage on the "5 V" line when everything is powered?

5V line I measure at 5.09V

You'd normally use a pnp transistor instead of npn for such a task (high-side switching). In your case the transistor might not be fully saturated because the potential at its emitter will rise due to the opto coupler.
Can you measure the voltage between emitter and collector?

a smaller base resistor could also improve things, try ~500 Ohm

After fiddling around, I have it working (for now).
I changed the following:

Connect the transistor to the "-" as I had in the schematic.
Replacing some wires (bad connections for 5VDC to Relay module)
Updating the Wemos D1 MINI pins (using D1, D2, D3 and D6 now)
Update Arduino code (adding "Pinmode(Dx, OUTPUT)" in setup)

Honestly I do not know exactly why it is working now, but I am happy for now.
I will look into switching the PNP for NPN transistor and reducing the resistor from 4.7kΩ to 0.5kΩ in case I start getting some issues (again) or have some more time for learning :)
Thank you very much for the help!

I don't know what the problem is with your LEDs, etc., but there is an error in your schematic.

The transistor collector (1) is connected to 5V- at (2). It should be connected to 5V+ at (3).

That was not just an issue in the schematic, but actually connected like that. After connecting transistor collector to the "+", the un expected switching on power on and resetting the arduino is gone. However, relay still not responding to GPIO low/high switching.
